# Help understanding jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery(function ($) {..}
```

I am trying to learn jQuery and came across some code that started like the above statement. What does that mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a shortcut for:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // ...
});
```

It sets up an event handler for when the document is ready to have its DOM manipulated.  It's good practice to initiate your jQuery code after the document is ready.  The first parameter `$` references the `jQuery` object so you can use `$` in place of `jQuery` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this allows you to abstract `$` into an anonymous function. As a few different javascript libraries use the `$` syntax you don't want to create conflicts. So instead you call jQuery using its explicit identifier `jQuery` and pass in `$`. Now you can use `$` all you want inside the anonymous function and not need to worry about conflicting with other libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Jacob is correct.

Other variations you will see along with `jQuery(function($){..}` are

```
$(document).ready(function(){...}
jQuery(document).ready(function(){...}
$(function(){...}
```

All wait until your DOM has fully loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Passing a function to a call to `jQuery()` has the effect of executing that function when the dom is ready.

The function is passed a reference to `jQuery` as the first parameter.  So, Setting the name of the arg in that function to `$` allows you to use `$` as shorthand for `jQuery` from within your function.  `$` is a global reference to `jQuery` by default, so you only need to specify `$` as a parameter in your function if you are overriding `$` elsewhere, for example by using `jQuery.noconflict()`.  This is common practice for plugin developers, since they can't be guaranteed that `$` has not been overridden by the plugin consumer.

Comment: Not so much "by default" but "if jQuery has been included as a resource".